# webgrid sort ipaddress based on numeric representation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sorting

I'm trying to sort a webgrid table that has IP Addresses displayed in dotted decimal octets by the integer representation of the IP. In asp.net webforms I could set the sort expression to the other column in the database to achieve the proper sorting.

Is there any way to "properly" sort the IP Address column in my webgrid?

I have a model that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;

namespace pcnweb_mvc3_v1.Models
{
    public partial class UPS
    {
        public UPS()
        {
            //this.Switches = new List<Switch>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int upsRecId { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(32)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(32)]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [StringLength(56)]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [StringLength(32)]
        public string Level { get; set; }
        [StringLength(16)]
        public string Circuit { get; set; }
        [StringLength(32)]
        public string Power_Feed { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|DHCP", ErrorMessage = "IP Address must be in the form of four octets 0-255: 255.255.255.255 or DHCP")]
        public string IP_Address {
            get 
            {
                if (ipOctet1 == null | ipOctet2 == null | ipOctet3 == null | ipOctet4 == null)
                    return "DHCP";
                return ipOctet1 + "." + ipOctet2 + "." + ipOctet3 + "." + ipOctet4; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (value == "DHCP")
                {
                    ipOctet1 = null;
                    ipOctet2 = null;
                    ipOctet3 = null;
                    ipOctet4 = null;
                    return;
                }

                //@todo Parseing could throw a number of errors: ArgumentNullException, FormatException, Exception
                byte[] temp = IPAddress.Parse(value).GetAddressBytes();
                ipOctet1 = temp[0];
                ipOctet2 = temp[1];
                ipOctet3 = temp[2];
                ipOctet4 = temp[3];
            }
        }

        public long ipTotal
        {
            get 
            {
                //(first octet * 2^24) + (second octet * 2^16) + (third octet * 2^8) + (fourth octet)
                return (long)Math.Pow(24, 2) * (long)ipOctet1 + (long)Math.Pow(16, 2) * (long)ipOctet2 + (long)Math.Pow(8, 2) * (long)ipOctet3 + (long)ipOctet4;
            }
        }

        private Nullable<int> ipOctet1 { get; set; }
        private Nullable<int> ipOctet2 { get; set; }
        private Nullable<int> ipOctet3 { get; set; }
        private Nullable<int> ipOctet4 { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<Switch> Switches { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the webgrid cshtml page:

```
@model IEnumerable<pcnweb_mvc3_v1.Models.UPS>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Name", canPage: true, rowsPerPage:25);
}
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        //grid.Column("upsRecId"),
        grid.Column("Name"),
        grid.Column("Description"),
        grid.Column("Size"),
        grid.Column("Location"),
        grid.Column("Level"),
        grid.Column("Circuit"),
        grid.Column("Power_Feed"),
        grid.Column("IP_Address"),
        grid.Column(
        format: (item) =>
        {
            var links = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.upsRecId }) + " | " +
                        Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.upsRecId }) + " | " +
                        Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.upsRecId });

            return Html.Raw(links);

        })
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got a workaround, its not the best but it works. I convert the IP address form the four octets stored in the database to the decimal representation, pass that to the webgrid so it can sort the value properly then provide a custom formatting function to take the decimal value and convert it back to dotted decimal form.

The code I used to do this is here:
https://gist.github.com/TechplexEngineer/5951594